# Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance on getting each value from picker

Tags: javascript, react-native, picker

So I have a picker that is mapped based on items from the database and I'm trying to get the value from each picker to send it back to the database. So far I have done this:

```js
this.state = {
            rating: null,
            arrRating:[]
        }

renderQuestion(){
        let panels = []
          this.props.companyQuestion.map((key, index) => {
            panels.push(
                <View key={index} style={styles.panel}>
                    <View style={styles.panelRow}>
                        <Text style={styles.panelText}>{key.question}</Text>
                        <Picker
                        selectedValue={this.state.rating}
                        style={styles.panelText}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                            this.setState({ rating: itemValue, 
                                arrRating:[...this.state.arrRating.push(this.state.rating)] })
                        }>
                        <Picker.Item label="Score" value="0" />
                        <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
                        <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
                        <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
                        <Picker.Item label="4" value="4" />
                        <Picker.Item label="5" value="5" />
                        </Picker> 
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
          })
        return panels;
    }
```

But I am having an error when I picked an item in the picker. It says

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

Comment: One thing I notice is that you don't return anything from inside `map` function. If you don't wanna return anything, you can use `forEach` instead.

Comment: @kiner_shah what do you mean?

Comment: `map` transforms one input to some output. If you don't wanna transform anything, just append to that array, you can use `forEach` instead.

Comment: @kiner_shah so my question is how do i get the values from each picker

Comment: This is not a complete example, cannot be reproduced. Please post a [mre].

Comment: @BillyRonaldoChandra are you using this ```@react-native-picker/picker``` library?

Comment: @NileshPatel yes